# In ASP.NET Core, can I tell if a model binding is from a query or from the body of a request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core, if I write an `IModelBinder` like so

```
public class BBoxModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {           
        ...
    }
}
```

can I tell if the binding is from a query with [FromQuery] or from the body of a request with [FromBody]?

I can't see anything on `ModelBindingContext` that looks like it can tell me this.

Does anyone know?

Thanks in advance. Chris

Comment: Doesnt it depend on what kind of request method your using? Get is FromQuery and Post is FromBody

Comment: You can have a GET body and a POST query string I believe so I don't think so?

Comment: Yes, you can send a request body with GET but it should not have any meaning. If you give it meaning by parsing it on the server and changing your response based on its contents, then you are ignoring this recommendation in the HTTP/1.1 spec, section 4.3

Comment: Link https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.3

Comment: Sure, so maybe this is the best way. I guess I was hoping there'd be something a bit more explicit. Thanks for your help @Webbanditten